# How do I get rid of a circular reference in a VBA dynamic range?

Tags: vba, excel, circular-reference

I am trying to create a user-defined Excel Function that, in part, counts all non-blank cells above the cell in which the formula is placed (technically from a specific cell that defines the first cell in the range). The trouble I am having is that copying the formula down is causing a circular reference. I don't want other users to encounter this problem. How can I avoid the circular reference?

I have been trying to solve the problem with:

```
Set CellOne = Range(“A10”)
Set CellTwo = Range(Selection.Address).Offset(-1, 0)
Set MyRange = Application.Range(Cell1:=CellOne.Address, Cell2:=CellTwo.Address)
CountNonBlanks = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange)
```

This code also causes the circular reference when copying down:

```
Set CellTwo = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(-1, 0)
```

The problem appears to be caused by the reference being relative to which cell is selected or active. I just want MyRange to end one cell above where the formula is placed irrespective of which cell is active or selected.

FWIW, the ultimate purpose of the user-defined formula is to return the next letter in the alphabet no matter how many rows below the prior letter the formula is placed. This native function works, but I was hoping for a more elegant *appearing* solution:

```
=MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",COUNTA(A$10:A10)+1,1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `=char(97+counta(a$10:a10))` 'more elegant'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Selection or Activecell in a worksheet's udf since those are constantly changing. Either pass a range reference into the udf or use application.caller to refer to the cell containing the udf as a range object.

I could edit this response to provide more specific help if you posted the whole udf or at least the declaration. Here's an example.

```
Public Function nextLetter()

    'since no reference is passed in, you might want to make this volatile
    Application.Volatile

    With Application.Caller.Parent
        nextLetter = Chr(97 + Application.CountA(.Range(.Cells(10, "A"), _
                                         .Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, "A"))))
    End With

End Function
```

Alternative with starting cell passed in.

```
Public Function nextLetter2(startRng As Range)

    'since only a single cell reference is passed in, you might want to make this volatile
    Application.Volatile

    With Application.Caller.Parent
        nextLetter2 = Chr(97 + Application.CountA(.Range(startRng, _
                                         .Cells(Application.Caller.Row-1, startRng.Column))))
    End With

End Function
```

Use like `=nextLetter2(A$10)`

Comment: Clarification: I would actually like the user to specify the location of the 'a'. The 'a' could be anywhere on the worksheet. Multiple instances of the UDF would just be below it - same column, greater row. Would you mind adding that feature to the code? I've been struggling with this macro for too long.